# "Bad file descriptor" with /dev/stdin using dd

Tags: dd, cloning, stdout

I've been using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321956/cloning-ubuntu-over-network) (Running off a live CD on both ends, and in root shell, as suggested in [another of my questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333490/permission-denied-using-dd-to-clone-main-drive?lq=1))
to clone one computer I've got set up to my liking to four others with the same hardware.

The first two clonings went smoothly, but when I try the
`sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/stdout | nc 1.2.3.4 5678`
(with the correct ip, of course) on the third computer to clone, after a short delay I'm greeted with the `root@ubuntu:~#` prompt again, rather than having to wait ~3 hours as it actually does the cloning.

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out of the nc on the receiving end, here's what I see:

```
0+0 records in  
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 1.6317 s, 0.0kB/s
dd: closing input file '/dev/stdin': bad file descriptor
```

The other clonings went fine, and all the computers I'm cloning to *should* be identical other than in name/ip address etc (Although I'm only human, and may have set them up slightly differently by accident, hence why I'm cloning to ensure they're all the same in the end).

Any idea why this one particular computer refuses to be cloned to (Or why the sender refuses to clone to it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm an idiot. Turns out the ip address for the receiving machine had changed on me, so I was trying to clone to the wrong address. I tried again with the new address, and things seem to be going smoothly.

Sigh...

Comment: @moon.musick Too early, I think. Isn't there a 1 or 2 day delay before you can accept your own answer?

Comment: Ah, I sort of misread the time of question creation, which is weird (there's no days number or anything).